# How to avoid full table scan with a bigint partition key

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I have a Product and Order table with these schemas:

```
Product: (
     id: bigint,
     created_date: timestamp
)
USING iceberg
PARTITION BY (id)

Order: (
    order_id: bigint,
    product_id: bigint,
    ts: timestamp
)
USING iceberg
PARTITION BY day(ts)
```

when I do `Order JOIN Product on Order.product_id = Product.id` I expect iceberg or spark can know where to find key to join, without scanning all data files. But it actually scan all rows to do JOIN operation

Is there anyway to avoid scanning the whole table in my situation?

Comment: Did you mean to *cluster* the data by id? It doesn't make sense (and will not work practically) to *partition* the data by high cardinality column such as id